# Callback methods annotated in a listener bean class must return void and take one argument: javax.persistence.PreUpdate

Tags: java, jpa

Estou tendo esse erro no meu console...

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Callback methods annotated in a listener bean class must return void and take one argument: javax.persistence.PreUpdate - public void digifred.model.aud.global.LogradourosEntityListener.preUpdate(digifred.model.global.Logradouros,java.util.Date)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.resolveCallbacks(CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.java:180) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.buildCallbacksForEntity(CallbackBuilderLegacyImpl.java:69) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

Não estou sabendo identificar o meu erro..

```
public class LogradourosEntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Logradouros target, Date modifiedDate) { 
        perform(target,Acoes.INSERTED, modifiedDate);

    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate(Logradouros target, Date modifiedDate) { 
         perform(target, Acoes.UPDATED, modifiedDate);

    }

    @PreRemove
    public void preRemove(Logradouros target,Date modifiedDate) { 
        perform(target, Acoes.DELETED, modifiedDate);

    }



    @Transactional()
    private void perform(Logradouros target, Acoes acao, Date modifiedDate) {
        EntityManager entityManager = BeanUtil.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        entityManager.persist(new LogradourosHistorico(target, acao, modifiedDate));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Callback methods annotated in a listener bean class must return void and take one argument
```

É o que diz a mensagem. Os seus métodos anotados com `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` e `@PreRemove` só podem ter um argumento. Em todos os seus métodos você colocou dois: `Logradouros target` e `Date modifiedDate`.

Ou você remove um deles, ou cria uma nova classe que tenha esses dois objetos como atributos e a utilize como argumento.